# get only disqus comment count number

Tags: php

Im using disqus on one of my projects. and im using comment count.

```
<span class="disqus-comment-count" data-disqus-identifier="article_1_identifier">First article</span>
```

Thing is i want to save the comment count on my database. Issue im having is without using span or a tag with disqus class you cannot get comment count. Is there are a way to filter and remove all the HTML in the code and just save the comment count in my database (Get a PHP string with just the counted number).

Any help is appropriated.

Comment: yes its possible, what have you tried and where is it going wrong? do you have a copy of the error produced?

Comment: @twigg 29 everything is fine i just want to get the comment count from above code applied in a php string without any HTML codes. Ex: `$comments = 2`

Comment: Since this comment number is loaded via JavaScript after the page loaded there's no way you can use PHP to store it. If you were using Wordpress (hopefully) the comment count will be saved on both Disqus and the WP database. I'm sorry i'm not much help.